# Amazon website shows "Deliver to Country". How can I change it programmatically?

Tags: php, flutter, yii2

**Problem :**

I am working on flutter mobile application. I am showing amazon website in flutter webview and on opening any item I fetch details for that product using **Zinc.io API** then handle ordering and shipping for that. My issue is that amazon by default shows "Deliver to Coountry_A" *(based on current user location)*. I can change it manually but I want to automatically set it to US always.

Because the country is set by default, there are many items that Amazon doesn't ship to the selected country so those items doesn't show up when users search for them. I want to show all products without the restriction of any country.

**Possible solution..?**

My server is in US. So, I had an idea but I don't know if it is possible or not. My idea is to render amazon webpage from my server (Php). Is it possible? Or is there any better solution to do this?

**Another website that do this :**

Cashbasha.com has an option on their website to browse Amazon. The view is exact replica of Amazon but it doesn't show "Deliver to Country". I am curious how are they doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I was able to find the solution.

> I am using `flutter_inappbrowser` package

I injected Javascript to change "deliver to country" to the desired country. This is my code

**How to inject js file from assets in flutter_inappbrowser**

```
onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
  webView = controller;
  controller.injectJavascriptFileFromAsset(
   assetFilePath: "assets/inject_ip.js");
},
```

**Write this code in assets/inject_ip.js**

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open('POST', 'https://www.amazon.com/gp/delivery/ajax/address-change.html');
    xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8');
    xhttp.send('locationType=LOCATION_INPUT&zipCode=19720&storeContext=generic&deviceType=mobile&pageType=Gateway&actionSource=glow');
});
```

Comment: I want to do the same in Python while using the selenium package. Is it possible?